# MouseAdapter vs MouseListener

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

I have a quick question about java. Why this DOES work:

```
list.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Mouse click.");
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

});
```

but this doesn't:

```
list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
    public void mouseClick(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Mouse click.");
    }
});
```

Thanks for answer in advance.

PS I had to add more text because that annoying post-adding-script won't let me as my post is mostly code.

Answer (score 7):

It's

```
mouseClicked
```

not

```
mouseClick
```

Small spelling mistake?

Comment: Ah well spotted. 1+. Another reason to use the `@Override` annotation to be sure that your method is in fact a true override.

Answer (score 0):

The abstract class MouseAdapter implements the MouseListener interface along with:

```
public void **mouseClicked**(MouseEvent e) {}
```

and not:

```
public void **mouseClick**(MouseEvent e)
```

This way should work:

```
list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Mouse click.");
    }
});
```